# Accessing Header values in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I am new to React, and I believe this is a unique situation.

So, I am creating a `React` Website `create-react-app`. When I run `npm start`, it will run on `localhost:3000`.

My next requirement is to have `Authentication & Authorization (AA)`. It is already created by another group.

What they give me is a small proxy website. Let's say it runs on `localhost:4000`.

When I want to go to `localhost:3000/Home`, I will type `localhost:4000/Home`.

`localhost:4000` will take care of `AA`, and if everything works out, it will forward to `localhost:3000/Home`.

The login information is added to `Http-Only & Secure` cookie by `localhost:4000`.

My question is how `React` can access it?

One of the solution is to use `react-cookie`. But it cannot access `Http-Only & Secure` cookie.

The workaround is to create another `proxy`. [React with Express](https://dev.to/loujaybee/using-create-react-app-with-express)

So, I create another proxy at `localhost:5000`.

The workflow becomes `localhost:4000` will handle `AA`. The result is forwarded to `localhost:5000`. `localhost:5000` will decide if it should forward to `localhost:3000` or redirect to `error` page. It works if my original website doesn't need to use those result cookies.

But `React` website needs to do some `POST` calls to a separate website at `localhost:9000`. `React` needs to pass the same `AA` result cookies to that website. If not, it will ask the user to login again.

I cannot change the cookies properties to non `Http-Only`, or copy them to another place.

So, the question is how to pass those cookies to `localhost:9000`?

Am I on completely wrong track because I couldn't find any similar posts online.

In short, can `React` access the header where some information like `username` is set, and `cookies` where actual tokens are stored? If not, what's the standard workaround?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to work around HTTP-only authorization cookies is a huge security risk, because in this case they could be stolen by third party scripts. Using proxies to bypass this limitation is certainly an inappropriate solution.

You are working in an environment with several services (localhost 3000, 4000, 9000) that share one authentication system. In this case your options are:

**1)** Make your *server* (the 3000 one) communicate with other servers on behalf of the client. If your client needs to POST to 9000, let it POST to a special endpoint of 3000. Your server will then query 9000 and return to the client with answer.

In this case you need to establish server-server authentication which is much simpler that client-server. But you have to handle authorization separately - if your clients may have different permissions.

**2)** If the 4000 server is only source of AAA, make it a **single sign-on** server then. There are a lot of solutions of this type. OAuth2 and JSON web tokens (JWT) are hot topics nowadays, with advent of microservices.

You could also talk to the team that developed `localhost:4000` and ask what their idea was.